# what is the format of date stored in SQLite through SwiftData?

Tags: swift, sqlite, swift-data

I am using SwiftData for persistence. Suppose I have a class:

```swift
@Model
class Book {
   var id: UUID
   var name: String
   var createdAt: Date

   .... // init
}
```

When I store a object in SQLite through SwiftData, I got the `ZCREATEAT` date column:

```sql
ZCREATEDAT 
----------------
730049036.810926
```

What is this? If I want to modify the value in SQLite for debugging purposes. How can I transfer the date such as 8/17/2023 to this kind of format?

Comment: `Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 730049036.810926)` is `2024-02-19 15:23:56 +0000`. You want to use a `DateFormatter` to transform a `Date` into a `String` with specific format., but keep it as a `Date`, it's usually better (especially if your format is "8/17/2023").

Comment: "I want to modify the value in sqlite", do you mean you want to change the field directly in the database or do you mean changing the property when debugging in Xcode?

Comment: Just open database with `SwiftData` and set values. What's a problem? Internal date format and that it's using sqlite shouldn't bother you.

Comment: Completely unrelated, as a matter of convention, I’d encourage you to capitalize the name of your class (i.e., `Book`, not `book`).

Comment: "What is this?" It is a Date! That's what a Date is: a number of seconds after a certain fixed reference point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Dates are stored as [`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780165-timeintervalsincereferencedate/) (the number of seconds since 1/1/2001). SQLite does not have a function that does that, but it does have [`unixepoch`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function, which is equivalent to the Foundation [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779963-timeintervalsince1970) (the number of seconds since 1/1/1970).

If you want to `UPDATE` this column from your SQL tool, you can subtract the `unixepoch` of 1/1/2001, e.g., set it to `unixepoch('2023-08-17') - unixepoch('2001-01-01')`. Or you might want to add time offset, as these are stored in UTC/GMT and if you wanted 17 August 2023 as understood in your timezone, you might want to adjust the time accordingly. E.g., for me in UTC-7, to update the `timestamp` of `Item`, it was:

```sql
update ZITEM
   set ZTIMESTAMP = unixepoch('2023-08-17T07:00:00') - unixepoch('2001-01-01')
   where Z_PK = 1;
```

Be forewarned that it is easy to screw up CoreData/SwiftData databases when manipulating them using third party tools, so I would encourage that you do your database manipulation from Swift, not SQLite tools.

---

To display dates in SQLite in user-understandable format, add the `unixepoch` of `1/1/2001`. E.g., to display the `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` date stored in the `ZTIMESTAMP` column of `ZITEM` table in a new column, `DATE`:

```sql
select *, datetime(ZTIMESTAMP + unixepoch('2001-01-01'), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') AS `DATE`
    from ZITEM;
```

If you would rather see these strings in UTC/GMT, just omit the `'localtime'` parameter.

Comment: You could shorten the sqlite date formatting a little by doing `datetime('2001-01-01', ZTIMESTAMP || ' seconds', 'localtime')`

Comment: Cool. Personally, I always get nervous with the idea of manually creating strings from numeric values (rounding issues, localization, etc.), but that appears to work. Thanks!